# How can i convert a dataset which contains 250K rows into a fusion backed dataset in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am currently in the process of template creation process for a project which needs the datasets contents to be included (The step to go from test to Pre-PROD/PROD). For the contents to be included of a dataset along with template, the dataset needs to be fusion backed. When i created a fusion sheet using the existing dataset, the rows are truncated to 25k rows syncing only these. But the existing dataset contains ~250K rows.  I am unable to locate in the documentation; how can i efficiently include all the datasets contents as fusion backed. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 250K fusion dataset sounds like a bit sub optimal. Some questions: 1- is anyone really going to even try to open it on fusion and use it? 2- Why do you need it to be fusion backed on your installed template?

Comment: @fmsf 1 &2. The purpose is to include the contents of the dataset when moving this dataset from Testing environment to PROD environment. This step is part of the template creation process. It is to be noted that, without having the dataset fusion backed, the dataset will be empty in PROD (During the template deployment process for a new project, the contents of all datasets are empty in PROD normally unless the dataset is fusion backed).  The goal is not to use any other functionalities in  fusion sheet but to back the dataset with fusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is to be noted that, without having the dataset fusion backed, the dataset will be empty in PROD

You should not use fusion for this! I would assume that while using a regular dataset you probably forgot to set the dataset to include the contents, you can do that by selecting a dataset and setting `includeDatasetContents` to `true`.

```
{
  "writeSchemaOnUpdate": true,
  "defaultWriteSchemaOnUpdate": false,
  "includeDatasetContents": true, <------ this must be set to true
  "buildDatasetPostDeploy": true
}
```

In the image below you can find a screenshot of the template creation and updating process of the Foundry Training Resources (the same project we use in the videos on our youtube channel).

[image: Foundry training resources template creation screenshot]

As a side thought, not wanting to criticise your design, just sharing some tips to improve it. Using a fusion sheet to hold data for transfer sounds like a very bad idea, and I would recommend you to refactor that. Fusion is a spreadsheet tool that users use manually like any other spreadsheet tool, if the data has 250k rows, it sounds like it can be error prone, hard to detect and fix should someone open it and edit anything incorrectly. There are better tools in foundry for data manipulation at these sizes i.e.: contour, transforms, code workbooks, etc...

Comment: Many thanks for the details above and indeed, i had to change the above parameter to 'true' +ensure that the dataset is fusion backed to include the contents of the dataset while promoting (from testing to Prodn). Unfortunately, only doing the above step is documented as not helpful. Copying from the Foundry documentation _'Including dataset contents is disallowed for datasets except those which are backed by fusion.'_. Very well aligned with your other thoughts above.

Comment: @mari - got it, thank you for the extra context. That sounds like it's something very specific to your stack, and sounds like specific permissions applied exclusively to/by you (you plural, whatever company you are working for). The answer I gave above stands correct for a regular foundry instance. Since you have specific self imposed limitations you'll have to address those internally.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was under the similar assumption that it is customized for use within a team. However i will want to try with only changing the above parameter to 'true' and see if that picks up the content.